# Select progressively "inner" and/or "outer" code blocks in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I can use vim commands like <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> or <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to automatically select everything within parentheses, brackets, etc.

Once I have such a selection, is there a way to then select the next outermost selection of that type? (Then from there, back to the next "innermost"?)

I am 99.9% sure I used to know how to do this - but can't find it or figure it out anywhere!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just repeat the object selection keys.  For your examples this would be `va}a}` or `vi]i]`.

I don't think that there is a way to then reduce the selection back to an inner block.  Other than to use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to clear the selection, ``` `` ``` to jump back to your starting point and then redo the initial selection.

Comment: Thanks - I did discover that - am still holding out for a way to "reduce" the selection. I am pretty sure (but not positive) that I used to know how to do that! :-O

Comment: You can also use count in this example to get the outermost selection, for example v2a} or v2i].

Comment: @Brad `o` switches to the "other end" of the selection, which you may find useful. Also `gv` will select the previously selected range.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little bit outdated, but are you talking about the [vim-expand-region](https://github.com/terryma/vim-expand-region) plugin?

Anyways, I still prefer qqx's way, since it's already built-in.

Comment: The  plugin is buggy. I wish there was something like Eclipse or CodeRush Refactor.